# Is 'request denial' a phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-usage

So I and my mom are having a debate over whether 'request denial' is even a phrase in the English language. Is it used in the common language, and if so where is it used?
My mother says that it could be used in this sentence:
'If you have any reason for this request denial, then please inform me'.

Can such a phrase like this exist?

Personally, I don't think that it's a phrase,  but my mother seems adamant about and I just want to know if such a phrase even exists.

Comment: Well it exists in your mother's sentence, though I think there are more elegant ways to word that. But if you google it you'll find a number of other instances.

Comment: yeah, I tried googling the phrase, but google doesn't seem to provide me with instances of its use. Instead, it gives me definitions of 'denial of request'

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22request+denial%22+examples

Comment: Bruh, the link that you sent takes me to a page where it shows me how to write a denial request letter. I just want to know if the phrase is used correctly if it even is a correct phrase

Comment: We would usually say "the denial of this request," but we use lots of  similar phrases like "school refusal" and "dentist appointment", so I don't  think you will find any rules saying it's ungrammatical.

Comment: to deny a request, the denial of a/this/that request, the request denial: all are fine. Mothers are often right.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a "phrase" in the sense of a fixed phrase - it is a simple collocation.

"Request denial" is two nouns. This is a common and productive way of producing compound nouns.

Nouns can act adjectivally to modify the following noun in this way:

Noun1 noun2 = the noun2 associated with noun1.

The Language Department = the department associated with language.

A beer bottle = a bottle associated with beer.

There can be several nouns together:

A beer bottle shape = a shape associated with a bottle that is itself associated with beer.

NB: When nouns are used together like this, they form one compound noun and cannot be separated.

The modern {Language Department}

- The Language modern Department

Because noun1 acts adjectivally, it is not common for noun1 to be plural.

But
The modern Department of Languages

The Department of Modern Languages

-> you will note that these mean different things.

Answer (score -2):

As this [page of research](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22request%20denial%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) shows, "request denial" is a term of the English language, but it is apparently a specialized term restricted to American English, and at that a term that has a defined sense only in the domain of the law.

The term is also found in American English in the domain of health. It is the act of a physician that consists in refusing a request that has been put to him/her by a patient.

> ([ref.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31907246/)) Abstract
> Background: Physician denial of patient requests is associated with lower patient satisfaction. Our objective was to explore factors that influence physician request denial and patient satisfaction after request denial.

> ([NLM](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29181542/)) When Physicians Say No: Predictors of Request Denial and Subsequent Patient Satisfaction.

Apparently, this term has not yet found its way into the dictionaries nor into British English.